# Can I install Powershell 5 Preview on Windows 8.1 32 Bits

Tags: powershell

According to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46889
you can download for Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8.1 Pro, and Windows 8.1 Enterprise

but none for Windows 8.1 non pro ?

Comment: To be honest I'd wait until it is released. I installed it and ended up uninstalling it shortly after after some crashing issues. I then got random random crash messages about PowerShell, even while not using it, until I flattened and re-imaged the laptop.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician OK thanks, I don't want to mess my pc. I wanted it for the -skiplast feature http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778704/how-to-remove-first-and-last-line-in-powershell