# How to extract lines between index 1 and index 2 to another csv variable?

Tags: powershell

Instead of outputting to a file with Set-Content like in [How to remove First and Last Line in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778704/how-to-remove-first-and-last-line-in-powershell)

```
$csv = Import-Csv in.csv -header Date,Time,O,H,L,C,V | 
       Select * -ExcludeProperty time |
       Foreach {$_.date = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.date,"yyyy.MM.dd",$null).tostring("yyMMdd");$_.v=1;$_} |
       ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
       for ($i = 1; $i -lt ($csv.Length - 1); $i++ { 
           $csv[$i] -replace '"' | Set-Content out.csv -encoding ascii
       }
```

I just want to put these lines in $csv2 var instead of out.csv. 
Set-Content does not work with var. How to do so (I don't have Powershell 5 ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code is that every time you call Set-Content it will rewrite the file and replace any content the file already have.

Consider adding the -append switch to Set-Content. This will add to the file instead of overwriting it. Remember to also make sure the file is empty befor you begin Writing to it.

I would also consider using a more simple way of getting the "mid" content of the file. Check the following sample. It might not cover all of your requirements, but is a simple way of getting Everything in an array except, the first and last element using the Range operator.

```
# First setup the test data
$filecontent = @"
Line 1 skip please
Line 2 include
Line 3 include
Line 4 include
Line 5 include
Line 6 include
Line 7 include
Line 8 include
Line 9 include
Line 10 skip please
"@

$filecontent | Set-Content in.csv
$content = Get-Content in.csv
$content[-($content.Length-1)..-2] | Set-Content out.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Instead of piping to Set-Content, just assign it to your variable. (BTW your original code was missing a closing parentheses on the for loop, which I have corrected here as well.)

```
$csv = Import-Csv in.csv -header Date,Time,O,H,L,C,V | 
       Select * -ExcludeProperty time |
       Foreach {$_.date = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.date,"yyyy.MM.dd",$null).tostring("yyMMdd");$_.v=1;$_} |
       ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$csv2 = for ($i = 1; $i -lt ($csv.Length - 1); $i++) { 
           $csv[$i] -replace '"'
       }
```